# php array_search() does not return key

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array ($arrayres) (example data)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
        (
            [description] => somedata
            [amount] => 52,6
            [b_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 138950106
                    [1] => 138950106
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [description] => somedata 
            [amount] => 4,9
            [b_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 138911857
                    [1] => 138911857
                )

        )
)
```

Then I have a query that returns the b_id in its results as well. I need to find which of the b_id's are  included in the array and their respective position in the array. So I perform an array_rearch

```
while ($dbres = $res->fetchRow(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC))
{

    $key = array_search($dbres['b_id'], $arrayres);
    if ($key)
    {
        $keys[] = $key;
    }

}
```

But there seems to be no match. print_r($keys) is always empty, although there are results that contain the b_id's in question.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok Thanks guys I got it. I thought (hoped) it would give me an array with the keys. In order to make the procedure simpler, I created another array $bid[] that holds only the b_id and (using the same keys), and made an array_search on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `array_search($dbres['b_id'], $arrayres);` you're searching for keys onto "the first layer" of that nested array and, of course, theare are only `0` or `1` as keys

You could do something like that

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arrayres);$i++) {
    array_search($dbres['b_id'], $arrayres[$i]['b_id']);
    if ($key)
    {
     $keys[] = $key; /* just follow your logic */
    }
}
```

and that has to be inserted into the while loop

Answer (score 1):

The array you are searching does not contain the b_id you are searching for. It contains an array that contains that bid.

So you need to loop yourself through the array of data you have, or supply array_search the whole array, if you can. One way would be this:

```
function has_bid($arrayres, $bid) {
    foreach ($arrayres as $k => $v) {
            // This is assuming $bid is an array with 2 integers.
            if ($v['bid'] == $bid) {
                return $k;
            }
            // And this is assuming $bid is one of the integers.
            /*
               Here, array_search will search for the integer in an array that contains
               the values you are searching for in the first level,
               not inside an array that is inside another one.
               You can think of it as array_search searching the first level of it.
            */
            if (array_search($bid, $v) !== false) {
                return $k;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And you would use this function like so:

```
$key = has_bid($arrayres, $dbres['bid']);
if ($key !== false) {
     // do something...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
if($key !== false){
     $keys[] = $key;
}
```

Comment: some times when key =0 and if we check ($key != false) then it will not conside value on 0th index.

Comment: But this isn't the answer to his question

Comment: he has already done coding .. while loop. I am asking him to remove if condition in while loop and put my condition..